# How to retrieve automated Test case names from Testlink

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testlink

We are using [Test link](http://www.testlink.org/) & Selenium webdriver for automation, we are updating the results of execution to Testlink once the execution completed.

We would like to retrieve the Test cases from Test links which are flagged as "Automated" so that we can manage the coverage of both Manual & Automation vs features and also select the Test cases for execution.

I could not find any method which can get me the list of test cases in Test Link API. It would be very helpful if anyone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [this](http://search.cpan.org/~teodesian/TestLink-API-0.011/lib/TestLink/API.pm) API doc? getTestCasesForTestSuite and getExecutionType might be the methods you are looking for.

Comment: A bit of explanation about how to use the 2 methods to solve the problem at hand and their syntax with examples would be a good help for our friends here!!!

Comment: Thanks for your response Oleksii. Syntax with examples would really help me to resolve the issue i am facing.